# Add log rotation support to airflow logs folder

Tags: docker-compose, airflow, log-rotation

I want to automate deleting all the log files(both scheduler and dag logs) that are older than 7 days.

The logs folder is mounted volume from the container -

```
  volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
```

I tried adding the below log rotation related environment variables to docker compose based on official documentation, but that is not working as expected.

```
    AIRLOW__CORE__LOG_ROTATE: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__MAX_LOG_AGE_IN_DAYS: '7'
```

Does airflow support log rotation?
Do we need to write a custom script to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use official [Airflow Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/airflow) it should contain [clean-logs](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/scripts/docker/clean-logs.sh) script, so you might add this service into your docker-compose file

```yaml
  airflow-log-groomer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
      AIRFLOW__LOG_RETENTION_DAYS: "7"
    command:
      - bash
      - /clean-logs
```